# Installation of Spectral Python

Tags: python, spectral-python

I am a novice user of Python. Since 2 days I am trying to install Spectral Python on my computer. I have already installed Python 3.5. But totally lost while adding the package Spectral Python. I have downloaded all versions of Spectral Python, while installing using Pycharm it is giving an error.

I would be grateful, if someone helps me by providing some very simple and easy steps in stalling the Spectral Python.

Comment: http://www.spectralpython.net/installation.html

Comment: adding any errors you got would help

Answer (score 0):

Basically something like this:

1. Download zip from Github (click this link: [spectral](https://github.com/spectralpython/spectral/archive/master.zip))
2. Unpack using your favorite (un)zip tool
3. Open terminal and switch to unpacked folder `cd ...`
4. Run `python setup.py install`
5. Check your console if installation was successful. If not, post errors here.

Comment: Dear Sir, Thanks a lot for the help. And sorry for the delayed reply. followed the same procedure as you mentioned but setup script exited with the error "Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required <Unable to find vcvarsall.bat>". To rectify this error, when I checked my computer, already VC ++ 10.0 is already installed and running. To confirm that again I downloaded a fresh VC++ 10 from the Microsoft's site and tried to install it. But installation resulted a error saying that already the required version is installed and running. Kindly help me to resolve this error. Kind regards. Lingaraj

Comment: Hi @LingarajHadimani, I actually had the same problem (with the installation of another library). I installed MingW and followed the steps [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2838827/811708), which solved my problem.